# Zapier multi step triggers and passing variables

Tags: zapier, brightpearl

I am getting stuck creating my own app to use within Zapier.  It is for an unsupported CRM
https://www.brightpearl.com/developer/latest/

I have been able to authenticate and create a test trigger - a simple call to retrive information about one product ID where the ID is provided in the request URL manually.

**Example Use Case**

Using an Email sent to a GMail account, search for a customerand add the body of the email as a note to the customer.

I can search using Zapier->Searches to retrieve a result.

The Brightpearl API search returns an ID for any matched contacts.
https://www.brightpearl.com/support/documentation/resource-search

The ID can be accessed in the json response

```
{
response: {
    results: [
      [
        4,
        "admin@email.com",
        "Primary",
        "Admin"
      ]
    ]
  },
  reference: {}
}
```

The ID is required to add the note later

1. How do I store the ID to use in the Action later?
2. How do I chain the events together so that the Action is called after the ID is captured?

I have gone through the Zapier documentation and cannot find example code which does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The trigger that exposes the ID in the API response (in this case, the Brightpearl search result) can be mapped to a subsequent action. You don't store data in Zapier - you just pass it between actions.
2. Zapier's multi-step interface lets you append actions which can accept any data returned from the previous step.

Comment: Thanks Matt - I have got my head around this a bit more now.

In the Brightpearl API, to create a contact you must create the address first, which returns and address ID.  I need to ensure that this step is done first (with just one line of data or a complete address). 

 I have two actions - one to create the address, and one to create the contact.  If I leave it to the user to do this as a multi-step, they wont know to create the address first.  How do I enforce this?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to mention this requirement for the "create contact" action. The "Address ID" field for that action could have additional text that says, "you must create an address step first, and use that ID."

Comment: Matt - thanks for this.  Your response is correct. You cannot store details within Zapier but can instruct users on how to correctly use the Zap.